# passing from stack to stack C++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to pass the top of stack `Chest` too stack `PlayerBag`.

I need to keep the two stacks separate as it is up to the player if they want to keep the items in `Chest` (which will then transfer them to `PlayerBag`) or discard them — `pop()`

I am having an hard time passing from stack to stack. Here is what I have got so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stack>
#define LootNumber 14
using namespace std;

// the 3 arrays stand for the 3 stats of each item
string NameOption[] = { "Stone", "Leather Gloves", "Dragon Gauntlets", "Chair Leg", "Dragon Scale Helmet", "Pebble", "Rusted Breastplate", "Dragon Breastplate", "Empty Bottle", "Chainmail Trousers", "Dragon Skin Trousers", "Broken Stick", "Dagger", "Dragons Sword" };
int RarityOption[] = { 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
bool SetOption[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };



class Loot      // grouping name rarity into set
{
public:
    string Name;
    int Rarity;
    bool Set;

    Loot(string N, int R, bool S) // constructor initialises each of the feilds
    {
        Name = N;
        Rarity = R;
        Set = S;

    }

};



class TreasureChest
{
public:
    stack<Loot> Chest;

    // defines default constructor
    TreasureChest(string E)
    {
        E = "Empty";
    }

    TreasureChest()
    {
        int i = rand() % LootNumber;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Chest.push(Loot(NameOption[i], RarityOption[i], SetOption[i]));
        }

    }

};

class PlayerBag
{
public:
    stack<Loot> Bag;

    PlayerBag(string E)
    {
        E = "Empty";
    }
    PlayerBag()
    {

        int *i = TreasureChest().Chest.push.Bag;
        void AddItem();
        {
            Bag.push(Loot(NameOption[*i], RarityOption[*i], SetOption[*i]));
        }
    }
};


class ShowChest
{
public:
    string BoxName;

    ShowChest()
    {
        BoxName = "Chest A";

    }

    void PrintContents()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << "Item: " << i << endl;
            cout << "Name:" << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Name << endl;
            cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Rarity << endl;
            cout << "Part of a set: " << TreasureChest().Chest.top().Set << endl;
            TreasureChest().Chest.pop();
        }
    }
};



// This prints a random selected item of loot to the screen
void PrintLoot()
{
    int i = rand() % LootNumber;
    Loot A(NameOption[i], RarityOption[i], SetOption[i]);
    cout << "Loot item: " << A.Name << endl;
    cout << "Rarity out of 3: " << A.Rarity << endl;
    cout << "Part of set: " << A.Set << endl;
}

//Gives player choise whether to keep or discard each loot item as it is revealed from the stack
void PlayerChoice()
{
    char Answer;
    cout << "If you want to keep the item press Y" << endl;
    cout << "If you want to discard the item press N" << endl;
    cin >> Answer;
    while (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;
        PlayerBag();

        // store item in bag array using pointer
        return;
    }
    while (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n')
    {
        cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
        return;
    }
    while (Answer != 'y' || Answer != 'Y' || Answer != 'N' || Answer != 'n')
    {
        cout << "To decide press Y for accept OR press N for Decline" << endl;
        cin >> Answer;
        if (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y') {
            cout << "Item stored in your bag" << endl;
            //store item in bag
            return;
        }
        else (Answer == 'N' || Answer == 'n'); {
            cout << "Item was discared from the Treasure Chest" << endl;
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
}


// function that prints the contents of TreasureChest to the screen whilst asking the player if they want each item.
void PrintTreasureChest()
{
    TreasureChest A;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        cout << "Item " << j << " in your chest is: " << endl;
        cout << "Name:" << (A.Chest.top()).Name << " Rarity out of 3: " << (A.Chest.top()).Rarity << " Part of a set: " << (A.Chest.top()).Set << endl;
        PlayerChoice();
        A.Chest.pop();
    }
    cout << "The chest is now empty" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can use [constructor initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) here. Like this `Loot(string N, int R, bool S) : Name(N), Rarity(R), Set(S) { }`. `void AddItem();` inside constructor looks weird. A typo, I guess? Could you please expand your question to describe your problem more specifically? Because it's not quite clear what's this you have hard time with :)

Comment: So im trying to create a bag like object so that when the player chooses to keep loot it gets stored somewhere. Then at the end they will be shown the items they have collected. the Loot works fine the problem im having is making a bag to store the loot in, this is just an extract and this is my first peice of code so im sure there are better ways to do most things iv done :( i just want it to work for now haha

Comment: You should also show your `main` function and whatever else is using the classes you pasted here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a stack specifically?

Comment: So im trying to create a bag like object so that when the player chooses to keep loot it gets stored somewhere. Then at the end they will be shown the items they have collected. the Loot works fine the problem im having is making a bag.(container)
p.s
yes typo i was trying lots of different ways to make it work :( 
I want to transfer the Loot which is on top of the Chest stack to a Bag.
I dont mind how iv tried stacks and arrays so far but im so confused iv only been doing code for a short time so i do apolagise for my stupidity

Comment: happy to use anything to make the bag

Comment: edited to show majority of code

Comment: off topic: `NameOption`, `RarityOption`, `SetOption` are calling out to be a single array of `Loot Options;`. Initializing: Loot Options[] = { {"Stone", 0, 0}, {"Leather Gloves", 1, 0}, ...}; Usage: Chest.push(Options[i]);

Comment: had'nt thought of doing that with the options thankyou.
this is literally my first ever piece of code so i know i sound like an idiot i am sorry

Comment: There is something very wrong on `PlayerBag()
    {

        int *i = TreasureChest().Chest.push.Bag;
        void AddItem();
        {
            Bag.push(Loot(NameOption[*i], RarityOption[*i], SetOption[*i]));
        }
    }` part.

Comment: I think you want a thing similar to what I posted on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclcwWlJsNEZRWW8
 — the `.top()` returns the top element of a `std::stack`, but does not modify anything in the stack contents; after you want to remove that element so you use the `.pop()` method. You should also verify whether the original stack has contents or not with `if(!TreasureChest().Chest.empty())`.

Comment: BTW, the code I posted will not do what you want. It seems you had not grasped well the notions of class, object and instance. Every `TreasureChest()` snippet you have, you are creating a new object instance of the `TreasureChest` class. So you are creating LOTS of objects in memory, when you really want to touch the **ONLY ONE** you wish to create. Think `TreasureChest` as it was `int` and you will get the point I am making.